# Adding an object to output w/ flat input

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to get data from one app into a format that another app will accept. I'm actualy trying to do exactly what this blog post is about but with jq instead of their program. https://www.tygertec.com/aegis-raivo-otp-translator/

Sample input data:

```
{
    "kind": "TOTP",
    "account": "google@gmail.com",
    "secret": "GoogleSecret",
    "iconType": "raivo_repository",
    "issuer": "Google.com",
    "timer": "30",
    "digits": "6",
    "counter": "0",
    "algorithm": "SHA1",
    "iconValue": "google.com/google-gmail.png"
},
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
{
    "type": "totp",
    "uuid": "b33ca6f5-7661-4289-afcc-ee9847c3e59a",
    "name": "google@gmail.com",
    "issuer": "Google.com",
    "note": "",
    "icon": null,
    "info": {
      "secret": "GoogleSecret",
      "algo": "SHA1",
      "digits": 6,
      "period": 30
    }
}
```

Most of this is just relabelling the fields, like from "kind" to "type" (I would like to figure out how to capitalize, but that is not my question), but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to make the "info" object.

I found some similar questions where map/reduce are used and tried reworking those into what I need, but I don't want to make an object for every key, and I'm generally confused about how to construct an object combining a) the keys I just need to do a simple "rename" (ex: type: .kind) on and a) the new (nested) "info" object.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I believe this is the fixed structure which do you want translate? Am I correct?

Comment: Where does `uuid` come from?

Comment: i actually don't know, but probably the destination app. i was planning to figure that out if just leaving it blank was a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to translate certain keys to certain other keys (with slight modifications sometimes), just create a new object, and assign the corresponding values (I didn't get where `uuid` is supposed to come from):

```
{
  type: .kind | ascii_downcase,
  uuid: "???",
  name: .account,
  issuer,
  note: "",
  icon: null,
  info: {
    secret,
    algo: .algorithm,
    digits: .digits | tonumber,
    period: .timer | tonumber
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tz0xF7ITpHy)

If you wanto pursue the "middle man" approach from the linked article, also show the intermediate srtructure you want to convert to/from.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this way was an option